# Self-planned driving tour of Iceland

Tags: iceland, adventure

We've just booked tickets for a mid-May visit to Iceland. We have 5 full days so we want to visit the Golden Circle and the sites of the South Island. We've looked at booking a self-drive tour with a company that gives you a trip planner and books accommodations, but we prefer to be more adventurous and plan our own trips. So, we have a few questions:

- Is it pretty easy to figure out your way around and find the sites we want to see, i.e. is signage pretty clear along the road?
- It is necessary to book glacier hikes and whale watching tours ahead of time or is it possible to book upon arrival?
- It is possible to wing it while we're there, or is it becoming such a popular destination that we should book everything ahead of time?
- Are Airbnbs a good alternative to hotels?

Comment: Lots of very different questions there. You should split them up in to seperate questions. (Except the last one - it's purely opinion. If you can get a more objective question about the issu,e then ask that).

Comment: You have lot's of good questions there (save for the last one), please split them up into different posts with one question only per post.